# FATFS integration on SPI NAND FLASH

Tags: memory, stm32, spi, flash-memory, fatfs

I'm trying to integrate FATFS file system on Micron NAND SPI FLASH. I'm using the SPI peripheral of the STM32L486RG as interface.

I have developped a low level driver through which I'm able to read, write and erase data from different locations in the NAND memory.
I have then integrated my Low-level driver APIs under `diskio.c` file in order they could be used by `fatfs` APIs.

I have successfully formatted the memory through `f_mkfs` (I'm getting `FR_OK` with both `f_mkfs` and `f_open` APIs and when debugging the `fs` object is containing the FAT signature).

However, when I try to write buffer into the file that I have created using `f_oprn` , I get `"FR_INT_ERR"` .

I have debugged my code step by step and I found that my `get_fat` function returns (1) as result which means that `an internal error has occurred` .

Any idea what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to erase the memory's sector you mean to write in - even though you write per pages and not per entire sector - and that's why using FatFs becomes tricky in NAND Flash.

Since your purpose is to bound the logical drive to the entire physical drive, you need to use the option `( FM_SDF | FM_ANY )` for the parameter `opt` into the `f_mkfs` function to format the memory.